# Getting started with responsive website layout

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I need to create a responsive layout, but I'm confused on how to start. I've looked up and found many resources, but it's all very overwhelming. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to get started? I can build a html/css website, but have never done anything in regards to mobile.

A few questions:
1) I've read you should build for mobile then move up, is this correct?

2) Should I start off with a template (or a grid, is that the correct term?) If so, any recommendations? (I've found some, but apparently I can't post links due to lack of rep)
This is the basic setup of the layout: http://oi57.tinypic.com/2en0rdf.jpg

3) Can you recommend any tutorials or tools that are a must?

4) What's the best way to test the layout? I've come across a couple (can't post links due to not having not rep

5) I've read about people using bootstrap, but I've used it in past projects and it seemed a little bloated. Although, it could be a good starting point?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Be aware that questions like this are typically flagged as opinion-based as there is no true correct answer.

Comment: Try to pick one thing at a time (navigation for example) and learn on a small level, work out what you can do and expand on that. There is a LOT you can do in responsive development, a huge array of frameworks (bootstrap is a good one), and remember it goes both ways, there are screens over 2000px wide now as well as mobile resolutions. Hongkiat has a very good list of tutorials - see http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-tutorials/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try explain a little for you :

1. I've read you should build for mobile then move up, is this correct? Some people start from smaller device to biggest (phone to desktop), but this is not a must. If you already have deep learning in coding responsive site you can start from Big to Small. But the reason behind start from small to bigger screen is if your page fit with the small screen then its easier to make it fit on bigger screen. So you take focus first on small.
2. Should I start off with a template? If so, any recommendations? Depend on you, if you dont want to make your hand dirty coding lots of element to fit your requirement you can using template. But for better understanding you may use grid CSS framework without UI styling like simplegrid or unsemantic 960.
3. Can you recommend any tutorials or tools that are a must? I'm not sure i can recommend. But do research, buy some book, start practicing and ask some expert for help if meet rock stone.
4. What's the best way to test the layout? If you coding using netbeans IDE they have built in tester with resolution option (Desktop & Mobile), or from browser plugin, on Firefox you can use Developer Kit and press Ctrl + Shift + M to activating screen simulator. And if you on chrome you can use Extension called Ripple, its have many device as a simulator.
5. I've read about people using bootstrap, but I've used it in past projects and it seemed a little bloated. Although, it could be a good starting point? Any CSS Framework is good, but the most famous is Bootstrap & Zurb Foundation.

Good Luck to you,

Answer (score 1):

> > 1) I've read you should build for mobile then move up, is this correct?

Yes, it is much harder to take a complicated desktop layout and convert it to a simpler mobile layout than vice-versa.

> > 2) Should I start off with a template (or a grid, is that the correct term?) If so, any recommendations? (I've found some, but apparently I can't post links due to lack of rep) This is the basic setup of the layout: http://oi57.tinypic.com/2en0rdf.jpg

Yes, to start I highly recommend you go with a framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) which have responsive grids.

> > 3 && 4) Can you recommend any tutorials or tools that are a must? What's the best way to test the layout? I've come across a couple (can't post links due to not having not rep

The best tool is a browser that you can slowly resize and watch how the elements rearrange as you resize it.  There are also websites that will display your page at different device widths.  For example http://quirktools.com/screenfly/.

> > 5) I've read about people using bootstrap, but I've used it in past projects and it seemed a little bloated. Although, it could be a good starting point?

Yes, [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) or any other framework out there is a good starting point.  Look at how they do responsive layouts and use that to learn from.

Answer (score 0):

1: I build for 1080p widescreen and move down. Everyone I know has a different opinion.

---

2: You can do a template, but you don't need one. In general, templates make things easier, but limit your control over your site, and your flexibility.

---

3: Two free ones:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design

http://www.palantir.net/blog/scalable-navigation-patterns-responsive-web-design

---

4: With Media Queries, you can do initial testing by resizing your browser, which is great. Final mobile testing will need to be done with an emulator, or an actual smartphone. You need to decide also if you want to support pre-4.0 Android.

Another good resource is http://browsershots.org/. It's free, and will  show you your site in a massive range of browsers.

---

5: Bootstrap ... the same implications apply for part 2. Makes your life easier but limits flexibility.